# arrange shuffled 2d string array(c programming)

Tags: arrays, string, shuffle

im new here.
i would like to ask for a sample code as i got an assignment in which require me to ask user to arrange a jumbled string array. so far i had successfully jumble the string. but then i got stuck on how can i compare user input with the jumbled array.

so basically, here is the problem;
1. i have to show the user a correct arrangement of a few sentences(string) where i saved them in an array.(done)
2. i have to jumble and show to users the jumbled sentence arrangement.(done)
3. the user must arrange the sentences in a correct manner as shown before.(stuck)

im sorry if u guys cant understand me well because im very newbie to programming somehow looking forward to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

- You create an array for original sentences
- You jumble sentences and save it on another array
- You print jumbled array and ask for user input
- You compare user input with original array

Answer (score 0):

as for me, i understand that your ideas requires user to retype the sentences. sorry if im wrong anyhow your idea just great.

if possible, can i make a code which require user to just enter the number as displayed. therefore, user should give this answer to rearrange the jumbled sentence; 4 2 3 1.
here is the output;

```
Original sentences
1.hello
2.my name is john
3.i love c programming
4.hope you can help me out


Jumbled sentences
1.hope you can help me out
2.my name is john
3.i love c programming
4.hello
```

here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100
char sentences[][SIZE]={"hello","my name is faiqwan","i love c programming","hope you can help me out"};
int main()
{
    char jumble[5];
    int i=0, j, same, randnum;
    srand(time(NULL));

    system("cls");
    for(i = 0; i<4;i++)
    { 
       randnum = rand()%4; 

     for(j=0;j<i;j++)
       {
            if(jumble[j] == randnum)
                same = 1;
       }

        if(same == 0)
            jumble[j] = randnum;
        else
            i--;
      same = 0;
    }
    int a=1;
    printf("Original sentences\n");
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d.",a);a++;
        printf("%s\n",sentences[j]) ;
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("Jumbled sentences\n");
    a=1;
    for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    {
        printf("%d.",a);a++;
        printf("%s\n",sentences[jumble[j]]) ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create another string array
- Fill new array with sentences[jumble[j]] (so new array will be as user input)
- Compare sentences array with new array

  - if it is same printout correct
  - else printout false